# Is it possible to move a Shape from a slide to another?

Tags: google-slides-api

I use the Google Slides API on a NodeJS server to edit a presentation and I can't find anything in the documentation on moving an object to another slide, a Shape for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You have to do this by getting the shape from the response of `presentations.pages.get`, removing it, and inserting it with `presentations.batchUpdate`.*

#### More Information:

In order to 'move' an object from one slide to another using the API, you in fact have to make two requests: one to remove the current object, and one to insert it into the new slide.

Firstly, you will need to make a request to `presentations.pages.get` in order to get all `PageElement` objects in the page. As per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/shapes), a Shape is an instance of a `PageElement` object which represents a shape on a slide.

The response of `presentations.pages.get` will be a [`Page` resource](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages#Page):

```json
{
  "objectId": string,
  "pageType": enum (PageType),
  "pageElements": [
    {
      object (PageElement)
    }
  ],
  "revisionId": string,
  "pageProperties": {
    object (PageProperties)
  },

  // Union field properties can be only one of the following:
  "slideProperties": {
    object (SlideProperties)
  },
  "layoutProperties": {
    object (LayoutProperties)
  },
  "notesProperties": {
    object (NotesProperties)
  },
  "masterProperties": {
    object (MasterProperties)
  }
}
```

The Shape will be contained within the `response['pageElements']` resource from this request and will be of the form:

```json
{
  "objectId": string,
  "size": {
    object (Size)
  },
  "transform": {
    object (AffineTransform)
  },
  "title": string,
  "description": string,

  // Union field element_kind can be only one of the following:
  "elementGroup": {
    object (Group)
  },
  "shape": {
    "shapeType": enum (Type),
    "text": {
      object (TextContent)
    },
    "shapeProperties": {
      object (ShapeProperties)
    },
    "placeholder": {
      object (Placeholder)
    }
  },
}
```

Once you have obtained the Shape object out of the response you get from `presentations.pages.get`, you will need to then create a [`CreateShapeRequest`](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#CreateShapeRequest) out of the retrieved properties:

```json
{
  "objectId": string,
  "elementProperties": {
    object (PageElementProperties)
  },
  "shapeType": enum (Type)
}
```

And a [`DeleteObjectRequest`](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#deleteobjectrequest) which can be used to remove the Shape on the previous slide:

```json
{
  "objectId": string
}
```

The `DeleteObjectRequest` and `CreateShapeRequest` can be both contained inside the same `batchUpdate` request. The request body should be of the form:

```json
{
  "requests": [
    {
      object (Request)
    }
  ],
  "writeControl": {
    object (WriteControl)
  }
}
```

The full documentation for the `batchUpdate` method can be seen [here](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/batchUpdate#request-body).

#### References:

- [Shapes | Slides API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/shapes)
- [REST Resource: presentations.pages | Slides API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages)
- [Requests | Slides API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request)
- [Method: presentations.batchUpdate | Slides API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/batchUpdate#request-body)